# Sql Server 2005 Puts square brackets around column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have recently moved a database from Sql Server 2000 to Sql Server 2005.  In the table designer, it insists on putting square brackets around a column named "Content"  I don't see Content on the list of reserved words for Sql Server, so I don't understand why it is doing this.  Is there a way I can prevent it?

Comment: "Square" and "Brackets" are not very good tags.

Comment: I was told the markup is a holdover from Access.  I don't care for it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the field has the same name as the table.  Sql Server 2000 did not seem to care about this potential ambiguity, but Sql Server 2005 does.  When I add a field named Content to a table that is not named Content, the square brackets do not appear.

pamela

Answer (score 12):

CONTENT is a keyword when defining an XML column with a schema.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163611.aspx).

Edit: The MSDN link is broken (per Champ's comment), so here is the relevant extract:

> Creating a typed XML column is as simple as adding the name of the schema inside parentheses, as you see here:
>
> `CREATE TABLE Foo(FooID INT, someXml XML(CONTENT FooSchema))`
>
> This statement indicates that the `someXml` column must adhere to the XML Schema Collection named `FooSchema`. You can specify that the XML must be a document or that it can contain a fragment by including the appropriate keyword, `DOCUMENT` or `CONTENT`, respectively. If omitted, the default is `CONTENT`.

Comment: all true tho they did forgot to add it to the list of reserved words on msdn :) anyway ... +1 nice link

Comment: It is not in the list of keywords for sql server on MSDN

Comment: link is broken. Here is an archived content of the link: https://web.archive.org/web/20141006161826/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163611.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't prevent it.  You can always add square brackets around a column name so it doesn't hurt anything.