# Select Query giving error in sql server R 2?

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2, select-query

I have a database called **Inspection**, and a table called **User**.

I first try to query it as follows:

```
select * from User ;
```

... and then like this:

```
select * from Inspection.dbo.User ;
```

Both of these are throwing the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: i solve it i have to write it like "select * from [Inspection].[dbo].[User]"  when i am giving it data base name in connection string then why it is acting like this ?

Comment: I see you found a solution already. My answer provides an explanation for it though, see below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use square brackets around the name of the table, since you use the name `user`.

Since `user` is a reserved word (has a special meaning on it's own), it can not be used directly as a table-name.

The square brackets tells MS Sql that in this case, `[user]` is the name of something a user  (you!) have defined (namely a table), and not a keyword in an operation on an actual user, as in for example:

```
CREATE USER slartibartfast (...);
```

Update: [More info about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917196/meaning-of-square-brackets-in-ms-sql-table-designer).