# Do table names with [Name1].[Name2] pattern differ from normal tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

When I look at Microsoft's sample *AdventureWorks* database, I see the table names follow a pattern such as:

```
[Person].[Address]
```

Does this kind of specification differ from a normal pattern such as:

```
PersonAddress
```

Is it only for readability or is there some other point to it?

Comment: Refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917196/meaning-of-square-brackets-in-ms-sql-table-designer

Comment: The [Person] is not a table name, but it is the schema's name which contains the table. [SQL SERVER – Importance of Database Schemas in SQL Server by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Using different schema names to organize related database objects is a best practice for databases that contain many objects.  The schema name can be leveraged as a namespace do differentiate and categorize objects.  It is generally best to explicitly specify a schema name even if objects are all in the same schema (default dbo) in order to improve performance of cache lookups.

Answer (score 1):

It's SchemaName.TableName

So  `[Person].[Address]` `!=` `PersonAddress`

Instead it'll be `Person.Address`

The [] are optional, they exist because if you have special characters, or a reserve word in the object name, you will not be able to call the object without them.

For example `select last name from people;` is not going to work,

instead you need select `[last name] from people;`

You can find more information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).