# What is difference in SQL Server between [] and ' '

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is actually difference between [] and ' ' I'm asking because when I wrote the query I couldn't write

```
SELECT *
FROM 'Order Details' 
WHERE OrderID = 11077
```

only possibility was

```
SELECT *
FROM [Order Details] 
WHERE OrderID = 11077
```

but I can rename `AS 'some name for column'` why ' ' is sometimes wrong?

I'm using the Northwind sample database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes denote a **string literal**, while **square brackets** (`[..]` - SQL Server/T-SQL specific) or **double quotes** (ANSI/ISO SQL standard) can enclose table (or column) names with spaces (`"Order Items"`), or names that start with a numeric (instead of a character - like `[1998 Sales]`).

So you should also be able to use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Order Details"
WHERE OrderID = 11077
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid spacess in table/column name. Brackets are required, when in table name have space, Sqlserver consider it 2 different word.

When we use reserved word or string as a column / table name, we required square brackets.

> Delimited identifiers
>
> Are enclosed in double quotation marks (") or brackets ([ ]). Identifiers that comply with the rules for the format of identifiers may or may not be delimited.

Please see the same question's answer:

[What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements)

[Meaning of square brackets [] in MS-SQL table designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917196/meaning-of-square-brackets-in-ms-sql-table-designer)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21779/sql-server-2012-is-putting-brackets-around-table-and-column-names

Answer (score 0):

This is example

```
select [first Name], [last name] from tablename where [last name]='name'
```

`[]` is used to add a space between two words in column like in above `[last name]`

and

`''` is used for a strings or execute the query as a string like `'name'` and also using in full query in parameter like

```
declare @perameter1
set @perameter= ('select * from tablename where name like =''name''')
```